# Go package with a loaded once set of data

Tags: go, singleton

I am writing a post code location lookup package, it loads in all uk postcodes from a csv, I would like to only load the data once I would like to know what is the best pattern to achieve this with Go.

```
type Location struct {
    Latitude float64
    Longitude float64
}

var postCodeCache = make(map[string]Location)
```

These are my data types, currently I have a function called LoadData and LookupPostCode(). Ideally I would want to import my package and it would automatically load the data if it was not already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two options:

1. The simplest is load the data in main before any other processing starts. If probability that you will read the data is very high and there is no other reason to avoid doing it immediately, why not?
2. Load the data with sync.Once. Something like:

   ```
   var dataLoaded sync.Once
   var data DataType = nil

   func LookupPostCode(some_args) {
       once.Do(func() {
           data = LoadData(some_subset_of_some_args)
       })
       // and here I know, that data are loaded
   }
   ```

Comment: Isn't `sync.Once` an unnecessary dependency? Couldn't `data` simply be `nil` when not loaded and not `nil` when loaded?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune A quick glance suggests there's 1.75 million UK postcodes. In the time it takes to load this data, multiple goroutines might have called `LookupPostCode`. Without the `sync.Once`, they'll each start loading the CSV. With it, they'll all block on the first call the finish.

Comment: @terinjokes Makes sense, except then I wonder why a lookup function loads data when the volume is that large. A possibly more reasonable idea along the lines of option 1 is to generate the map outside of the package and have it loaded with the rest of the package. Potentially slow import, but it'd likely be faster than importing it from a file every time the package is imported. Of course, this assumes that a map literal of that magnitude is supported by the implementation… I'm unaware of any limitations, so AFAIK it's a viable solution.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune True. For this use case, if it was my application I'd either load the data at application startup and pass to the object that would be doing the lookups or, if the data changes very infrequently, like Unicode CLDRs, a generated package that gets imported. This doesn't make option 2 any less valid for other use cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use init() function in your package to do this.

Or, if it does not change frequently, you can convert your CSV into a Go Map definition in a separate .go file and it will be 'loaded' at the compile time.